# Wire buttons to select/unselect from dynamically created listboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This function wires the fourth instance of a dynamic control (a ListBox with select all/unselect all buttons):

```
function pageLoad() {

    $('#MainContent_lbx4_AllLB').live("click", function () {
        $('#MainContent_lbx4_RegionTypeLB').find('option').attr('selected', true);
    });

    $('#MainContent_lbx4_NoneLB').live("click", function () {
        $('#MainContent_lbx4_RegionTypeLB').find('option').attr('selected', false);
    });

}
```

I works but like I mentioned, it only works on the fourth instance.  How I can I find how many of them there are on the page, and use that number to loop through and wire them all ?

Comment: Do you have the same ID's for each ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your events like below. This would work for all instances of your control

```
$('[id^=MainContent_lbx]').live("click", function () {

    //split by underscore
    var main_id = $(this).prop('id').split('_'); 

    //pop last element in the array to check for AllLB or NoneLB
    var popLast = main_id.pop();

    //replace AllLB or NoneLB with RegionTypeLB
    main_id[2] = 'RegionTypeLB';
    var regionId = '#' + main_id.join('_');

    if(popLast == 'AllLB')
    {
        $(regionID).find('option').attr('selected', true);
    }
    else if(popLast == 'NoneLB')
    {
        $(regionID).find('option').attr('selected', false);
    }
});
```

From **[jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**, As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). It's removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: But how can I differentiate the ending, i.e. AllLB vs NoneLB.  As NoneLB needs to set selected to false.

Comment: The `.live()` function isn't just deprecated now, it's been removed entirely in versions 1.9+.

Comment: @Krishna: that works great !  One tiny correction was for the separator in the join, i.e. join('_').  Quick question: Should I include :button just before [id^=MainContent_lbx] to only look at button elements, as MainContent_lbx represents buttons but also ListBoxes ?  Thx.

Comment: @CrniKrv - glad I could help. You could attach this event to multiple elements if you like.

Answer (score 1):

soundslike you need to take a look at using advanced selectors - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

If all the list box ids are similar, you can use somethign like this

```
$("[id^='MainContent_lbx')
```

this will target all elements with an ID starting with "MainContent_lbx"